# Trying to run Locustio through an Nginx server

Tags: python, ssl, nginx, load-balancing, locust

Setup:
I have 3 servers 
Server 1 - Nginx and Locustio are on this box
Server 2 - Holds a django project on port 8001
server 3 - Holds a django project on port 8001

My Nginx box has an ssl certificate and is accessible through https://example.website.com/project
When I put that in the URL everything works fine, and it does a round robin on server 2 and server 3.

```
listen 443 default_server ssl;
server_name www.example.website.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert_bundle.crt; 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.website.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers   HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    # server_name localhost;

   location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

       proxy_pass http://backend_hosts;
       proxy_redirect off;

       # Handle Web Socket connections
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

   }
```

The problem occurs when I try to access it through Locust.

My locustfile.py

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

def index(l):
      l.client.get("/")

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
      tasks = {index:1}
      print "executing"
  # def on_start(self):
  #    login(self)

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
      task_set = UserBehavior
      min_wait = 5000
      max_wait = 15000
```

When I run locust by doing:

```
locust --host=https://127.0.0.1/project
```

All of the requests fail. They don't access the correct servers (It looks like it's not being called by Nginx?)

When I run locust by doing:

```
locust --host=https://example.project.com/project
```

I don't get any feedback from the web browser (no requests are being sent)

The command line log does give some feedback though:

```
[2016-10-17 11:08:45,550] msg-queue/INFO/locust.runners: Hatching and swarming 10 clients at the rate 1 clients/s...
[2016-10-17 11:08:55,557] msg-queue/INFO/locust.runners: All locusts hatched: WebsiteUser: 10
[2016-10-17 11:08:55,557] msg-queue/INFO/locust.runners: Resetting stats

^C[2016-10-17 11:10:20,419] msg-queue/ERROR/stderr: KeyboardInterrupt
[2016-10-17 11:10:20,419] msg-queue/INFO/locust.main: Shutting down (exit code 0), bye.
 Name                                                          # reqs      # fails     Avg     Min     Max  |  Median   req/s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total                                                              0     0(0.00%)                                       0.00

Percentage of the requests completed within given times
 Name                                                           # reqs    50%    66%    75%    80%    90%    95%    98%    99%   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So my question, what is the proper way of accessing server 2 and 3 with Locust?

Locust is on the same server as Nginx. I've tried accessing it with the

EDIT:

When I run locust by doing:

locust --host=https://127.0.0.1/project

```
[2016-10-17 15:50:38,509] msg-queue/ERROR/requests.packages.urllib3.connection: Certificate did not match expected hostname: 127.0.0.1. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Feb  5 14:32:38 2017 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'example.website.com'), ('DNS', 'www.example.website.com')), 'subject': ((('organizationalUnitName', u'Domain Control Validated'),), (('commonName', u'example.website.com'),))}
[2016-10-17 15:50:38,540] msg-queue/ERROR/stderr: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my nginx config file. It wasn't allowing localhost requests

```
server_name localhost;
```

Adding that line seemed to solve my issue.